# Dreamfactory Firebird Service

Tags: dreamfactory

I couldn't solve the issue reported [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72170905/dreamfactory-service-control-panel).

Therefore after several hours of trying and several reinstalls, I did reset the server and installed ubuntu20, so I could use the installer. I omitted the installation of KeyHelp, because KeyHelp and dreamfactory seem to interfere.

Finally I installed firebird3.0, via

```
apt install firebird3.0-server
```

and afterwards (because it did not work) via the description provided [here](https://guide.dreamfactory.com/docs/installing-and-configuring-dreamfactory/#install-the-firebird-driver).

Then I added the pdo_firebird.so driver in the php.ini file.

I can work with firebird via isql-fb. And I even can attach to several databases via DBBeaver on my MacBook using ssh tunnel.

But whatever I try I cannot get the service running on dreamfactory. I did setup a service as firebird. Provided the following data:

```
host: localhost
port: 3050
database: /db/employee.fdb
Username: SYSDBA
Password: (the correct password)
```

I tried several settings for the rest of the fields (empty, utf8, etc.).

When I save the settings I receive:

> TestResult for fdb:
> Test connection failed, could just be a typo. Please check config credentials for Service Name: fdb

If I goto the Data tab and select Firebird as Service, I receive:

> DreamFactory Utility Module
> The server returned an unknown error.

I am out of ideas. I even manipulated the rights for the database file by providing 666 rights (rw to all).

Does anybody have any idea?

Unfortunately the dreamfactory page only concentrates on paying customers. Nearly no questions are answered on their page. Maybe somebody can help me here?

Comment: I ckecked some log files and found: [2022-05-29T08:54:30.369755+00:00] local.ERROR: Declaration of DreamFactory\Core\Firebird\Database\FirebirdConnection::table($table) must be compatible with Illuminate\Database\Connection::table($table, $as = NULL) {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\F>. So it seems that the table name might not be correct. I tried /db/employee.fdb, but also employee as an alias that is configured in databases.conf. I also tried another table.

Answer (score 0):

The comment above showed me the way to the solution.

In fact in the file FirebirdConnection.php the method table() is overwritten, by extending the base class Connection.

The original Baseclass uses:

```
public table($table, $as = NULL)
```

FirebirdConnection had the method head:

```
public table($table)
```

although the second parameter is optional. Php7.4 does not accept that.
I changed the content of the File FirebirdConnection.php to use the upper method head.

Now it works!